# Looking for a value in a HUGE array?

Tags: php, arrays, search

I am reading a text file with product numbers into an array, the file consists of ~30000 lines. So I will have an array with ~30000 elements.

I am now searching for a certain number in that array using the `in_array` function, which seems to be taking a long time. Is there a way to search faster in that text file or the array?

The text file has one number like 4732934322 on each line.

Ideas?

Comment: if the array was sorted, you could find numbers in it much faster using [binary search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-php/)

Comment: Can you define "a long time"? How often do you need to do the search? If you're searching the same data multiple times for different values, could you import it into a database? Could you search for the value as you're loading the file, rather than loading it all into an array and then searching the array afterwards?

Comment: if you'd use the product key as index, you could use `isset()`.. `in_array()` gets slower, the more data it has to search